# Web App architecture questions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

**Background:**
I am an intermediate web app developer working on the .Net Platform. Most of my work has been defined pretty well for me by my peers or superiors and I have no problem following instructions and getting the job done.

**The task at hand:** 
I was recently asked by an old friend to redo his web app from scratch. His app is extremely antiquated and he is getting overwhelmed by it breaking all the time. The app in question is an inventory / CRM application and currently each customer requires a new install of the app (usually accomplished by deploying it on a different domain on the same server and pointing to a new database).

Currently if any client wants any modifications to the forms such as additional fields, new features, etc my friend goes in and manually adds those fields to the forms, scripts, database etc. As a result all installs of this application are unique. There is no one singular source repository and no one single version of this app. Generally new features are overtime rolled into the other sites, but still this is done on an individual site by site basis.

I will be approaching this on a very modular basis. Initially I will be coding a module that will query an external web service for some data, display and store it, and periodically update it automatically. The next module will likely be for storing and displaying inventory data. This way I want to over time duplicate the current feature set of his app 100% but do it incrementally.

**The Million Dollar Questions**

1. I want to make the app have user
   configurable form fields. The user
   should be able to go to an admin
   page, create a new forms page of a
   certain category, and then specify
   what fields he wants in there. He
   could say 'create a new text field
   called Item # and make it a
   requirement" and that will get
   stored somewhere. All forms will be
   dynamically rendered to screen based
   on what the user has configured. Is
   this a good way to go about the
   problem of having no idea what a
   customer could want in a form? and
   thus be able to store and display
   form data of any sort ? What sort of
   design pattern should I follow here?

   I am familiar with asp.net and
   the .net framework in general and
   have decent knowledge of javascript,
   html, silverlight, jquery, c# etc
   etc. I can work my way around web
   apps in a good way, but I am not
   sure what sort of framework or tech
   I should use to accomplish this
   task. Would ASP.net 3.5 webforms be
   the way to go? or should I look into
   ASP.NET MVC? Do I use jquery and ajax for
   complete decoupling of frontend and
   backend ? or will a normal asp.net
   page with some spattering of ajax
   thrown in working with a codebehind
   be the order of the day?

Just looking for general advice before I start.

I am currently thinking of using ASP.NET 3.5 webforms, jquery for clientside animation, ui, manipulation and data validation, and sqlserver + a .net or wcf webservice for backend.

Your advice is much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently implemented a white-label ecommerce system for an insurance company that allowed each partner to choose their own set of input fields, screens, and order the flow of the application to suit their individual needs.

Although it wasn't rocket science, it added complexity and increased development time.

Consider the user configuration aspect very carefully In hindsight both my client and their clients in turn, would have been happy with a more rigid system.

As for the tech side of your question, I developed my project in VS2005, using asp.net webforms and webservices with a SQLserver back end, so the stack that you're looking at is definitely capable of delivering a working product. ASP.net MVC will almost certainly help as far as testability goes.

The biggest thing I would change now if I was going to start again would be to replace the intermediate webservices with message based services using nServiceBus, MassTransit or the like. While the webservices worked fine, message based communication should be quicker and more reliable.

Finally, before you start to code, make sure that you understand the current system's functionality inside and out. If the new system doesn't do something that the old system did, it will be pretty obvious to the end users straight away.

Comment: how did you manage the "allowed each partner to choose their own set of input fields, screens, and order the flow of the application to suit their individual needs" part ?

Comment: I had tables in the db for flow, forms, controls and control items that were organised into sets that could be assigned to each end client. Each webform inherited from a class that contained the code to get the config out of the db and build the content in the right order & load into a repeater control. Then when the use pressed continue, another method went through the controls collection saving the values to the db. Finally it would check the flow config in the db, load the next form and start again building the content.